# Why the deployed spring boot jar shows different unnecessary messages in the log compared to development machine?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, logging, spring-boot-actuator

I created an executable jar using maven "mvn clean package". The jar is successfully created. When I run this jar using java -jar project.jar on my development machine following is the logs which I see (which is correct ).

```
(Expected and Correct Output)
On Development machine:
=======================================================
 
2021-07-02 14:11:27 -  IP host address is : 10.80.203.28
2021-07-02 14:11:27 -  Hostname is : DESHPANY01
2021-07-02 14:11:27 - 10.80.203.28

=============================================================
```

```
Same jar On Deployed server:
2021-07-02 11:02:24 -  IP host address is : 10.232.167.120
2021-07-02 11:02:24 -  Hostname is : illin2189
2021-07-02 11:02:24 - 10.232.167.120
2021-07-02 11:05:21 - Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1625213121591 sessioncount 0
2021-07-02 11:05:21 - End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 1 expired sessions: 0
2021-07-02 11:08:21 - Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1625213301594 sessioncount 0
2021-07-02 11:08:21 - End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 1 expired sessions: 0
2021-07-02 11:11:21 - Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1625213481597 sessioncount 0
2021-07-02 11:11:21 - End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
2021-07-02 11:41:16 - Security checking request GET /logfile
2021-07-02 11:41:16 -   No applicable constraints defined
2021-07-02 11:41:16 - Loading persistent provider registrations from [/tmp/tomcat.6109942763391894578.9091/conf/jaspic-providers.xml]
2021-07-02 11:41:16 -  Not subject to any constraint
2021-07-02 11:41:16 - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-07-02 11:41:16 -     findClass(java.lang.ObjectCustomizer)
2021-07-02 11:41:16 -       findClassInternal(java.lang.ObjectCustomizer)
2021-07-02 11:41:16 -     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
2021-07-02 11:41:16 -     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
2021-07-02 11:41:16 -     findClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolverCustomizer)
2021-07-02 11:41:16 -       findClassInternal(org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolverCustomizer)
2021-07-02 11:41:16 -     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException

2021-07-02 11:41:16 -     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
2021-07-02 11:41:16 -     findClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolverCustomizer)
2021-07-02 11:41:16 -       findClassInternal(org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolverCustomizer)
2021-07-02 11:41:16 -     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
```

I am using spring boot actuator and its /logfile endpoint to see the logs. I tried the --debug:false as parameter to the jar as well, but it didn't worked.

Why is it showing ClassNotFoundException and StandardManager messages in my log ? I just want to show my application log messages and nothing from spring boot. How to resolve it?

following is the application.properties file:

```
spring.main.log-startup-info=OFF
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core = OFF
logging.file.path=/
logging.file=logs/recycler_logs.txt
logging.level.com.alfred=INFO
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=OFF
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=ERROR
logging.group.tomcat=org.apache.catalina, org.apache.coyote, org.apache.tomcat
logging.level.tomcat=ERROR
logging.level.web=ERROR
logging.pattern.file=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
```

Following is the pom.xml:
I have mentioned packaging as jar and used boot plugin too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <start-class>com.alfred.recycler.AlfredSuspenseRecyclerApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>

    </properties>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.10</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.19.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You are mixing different spring boot versions...you should use only one ...

Comment: agree with other comment, AcceptHeaderLocaleResolverCustomizer 
 is now in a different package with a very slightly different name (org.springframework.web.server.i18n). If this is a new project I'd probably avoid SB 1.5.x as its unsupported, 2.5.x is the latest.

Comment: @jeremyt unfortunately i cant use spring 1.5x as its a production server with java 1.7

Comment: @khmarbaise thankyou for pointing out. I have changed the actuator version. Unfortunately it still persist :(

Comment: What happens if you set the version for `spring-boot-loader-tools` to 1.5.9 too?